# Which dynamic container type to use?

Tags: c++

I'm writing code for a router (aka gateway), and as I'm receiving and sending packets I need to use a type of container that can support the logic of a router. When receiving a packet I want to place it in the end of the dynamic container (here from and on known as DC). When taking the packet out of the DC for processing I want to take it from the front of the DC.

Any suggestion on which one to use?

I've heard that a vector would be a good idea but I'm not quite sure if they are dynamic..

EDIT: The type of element that it should contain is a raw packet of type "unsigned char *". How would I write the code for the DC to contain such a type?

Comment: Sure you're needing LIFO (last in, first out, usually a stack) data structure? A router typically needs a FIFO datastructure, e.g. a queue

Comment: @StoryTeller no, OP wants to pop from the front. Vectors are very inefficient at doing that.

Comment: @mfontanini, yes, you are correct. The OP said "LIFO" at the time of my comment.

Comment: @mfontanini But for small batches of data still possibly more efficient than either lists or deques.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes I did and I noticed that error quite quickly and removed it ;)

Comment: @Zeliax: question: does the container need to manage the memory for the packets itself, or we have to assume it's already taken care of in some other way?

Comment: @KonradRudolph probably. It really depends on how much data he's going to buffer.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Well, as the packet is received in a thread I receive a pointer of type "unsigned char *" so basically I think the packet is stored somewhere in the memory of the computer and I'm given the address to it. I just want to keep track of the packets so that I can process them later on

Comment: @Zeliax: ok, fine, then the FIFO must simply contain `unsigned char *`. I asked because, if memory management was in the duties of the FIFO, there was also the choice of the best element type to use for it.

Comment: @Zeliax here's a little graph for helping to choose among containers. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4226656/356440

Comment: @KonradRudolph: faster than lists - most probably, but how it can be faster than deque? Even a case of repeatedly adding/removing an item that requires a new deque bucket can be handled effectively. The main question is: is it worth to use `std::vector` here even if performance measurement on some approximated to reality cases shown it's a bit faster than deque?

Comment: @Andy “is it worth using it” – if the packet handling is a bottleneck (and it probably is) then yes, absolutely. But I agree that it’s probably not faster than a deque: the latter has more management overhead but if only *one* packet queue is needed then this shouldn’t be an issue in terms of memory, and it’s only set up once.

Comment: @AndyT: I can fairly easily believe that if the size of the queue is close to 3 for long sequences of pushing/popping, and never 0, then in some `std` implementations `vector` will beat `deque`, simply because the `deque` occasionally allocates memory whereas the `vector` never does, and the cost of copying 2 pointers downwards in the vector is negligible. Obviously that's a specific use pattern, but you did ask how *can* a vector be faster than deque, not whether it really will be :-)

Comment: @KonradRudolph I will be using 2-3 packet queues in total. 1 for receiving on the 2 interfaces connected, and 2 for "saving" the packets after processing, leaving them ready for sending.

Answer (score 3):

`std::deque<unsigned char *>` is the obvious choice here, since it supports efficient FIFO semantics (use `push_back` and `pop_front`, or `push_front` and `pop_back`, the performance should be the same).

In my experience the `std::queue` (which is a container adapter normally built over `std::deque`) is not worth the effort, it only restricts the interface without adding anything useful.

Comment: I would say `std::deque` is implementation details here when `std::queue` represents logic requirements and uses `std::deque` under the hood

Comment: @AndyT: I know, but the performance guarantees (which are the only thing that matters here) are in `std::deque`; `std::queue` only dumbs down the interface without adding anything useful (not even type erasure of the underlying container, since it is a template parameter), which often is a problem when you need to do anything else besides pushing and popping.

Comment: The purpose of `std::queue` is to adapt one interface (consisting of `SequenceContainer` plus some of the optional Sequence functions) to another interface (that of the Abstract Data Type usually called a "queue" in CS literature). If you want to use some other interface than queue then simply don't use an adaptor whose sole purpose is to provide that interface. I have a sneaking suspicion that `std::stack` and `std::queue` are there primarily to demonstrate in the standard that container adaptors are possible.

Comment: FWIW the two also provide between them a (compile-time polymorphic) interface that has `push` and `pop` but is agnostic as to which order the elements come back off. So you could in theory write a function template that doesn't know whether it's going to be passed a FIFO or a LIFO parameter, or even a `priority_queue`. Not that I can immediately think of any use for that either ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: that's exactly the impression I always had, it was included just "because we can", without thinking about how useful they could be. What is doubly-stupid is that the stdlib containers are already ADT (excluding `std::vector`, there's no mandated implementation, only performance requirements), so this is just (mostly broken and useless) abstraction for the sake of itself. The only container adapter I ever found useful was `std::priority_queue`, because it actually *does something* besides dumbing the interface.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: meh. I don't think it's stupid, even if it doesn't provide any functionality other than the change of function names. If you're not interested in restricting interfaces just for the sake of it then you should be writing javascript, not C++ ;-p

Comment: @SteveJessop: you almost got me, my other language of choice is Python, where "really private" data (via name mangling) is an afterthought and you look like a jerk anyway if you actually use it. :)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I mostly write Python these days, I picked "Javascript" solely for some variety.

Answer (score 2):

For a router, you probably should use a fixed size custom container (probably based around std::array or a C array). You can then introduce some logic to allow it to be used as a [circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). The fixed size is extremely important because you need to deal with the scenario where packets are coming in faster than you can send them off. When you reach your size limit, you then flow off.

With dynamically re-sizable containers, your may end up running out of memory or introducing unacceptable amounts of latency into the system.

Comment: I am working with a theorem as of where the size of the memory shouldn't be a problem. Right now the packets that I receive are of size 1518 byte at max and they are stored somewhere on the ram of the computer. The computer I am supposed to implement this program on has around 2 GB of RAM, so again it should not be a problem when I'm working with processing time of around 10 ms for receiving, processing and sending

Comment: It really does not matter how much memory you have, if you are receiving packets faster than you are processing them, at some point you will run out of memory. More memory just means it will take a bit longer. Flow control is essential to ensure you are receiving and processing at the same speed.

Comment: @doron: he's not actually managing the memory for the packets, they are handled by another thread; all he wants here is an efficient FIFO container for `unsigned char *`. If packets are coming too fast, this piece of code (a FIFO of pointers) is the last of his problems (the memory will be exhausted by the actual packet data way before the list of pointers has some relevance).

Comment: @Matteo you are missing the point, it is not about the container running out of memory but rather about flow control. You must have a good answer as to what will happen if you are pushing packets into your container faster than you are popping them out. Even if you do not run out of memory you may potentially introduce huge about of latency (buffer-bloat) into your system.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: How `char*` memory can be managed automatically (implicitely)? The only case I can imaging is that packets are stored in network interface buffers which are definitely of limited size. In this case it's important to have the queue at most the size of this buffer, in opposite case you can store orphaned pointers. And if memory is not managed automatically, the queue again should be of limited size.

Comment: @AndyT: that's what he said in the comments when I asked him specifically about the management of the packet data. There's another thread which takes care of it. If packets are coming too fast, it will be that thread's problem, since it has to do the heavy lifting (receiving and storing the packet data); here we are just handling an accessory list of pointers to stuff managed elsewhere.

Comment: (that's why I'm not too preoccupied about our FIFO growing out of control - the other thread will run into problems way before our container explodes, so it must already be equipped to deal with this stuff)

Comment: @MatteoItalia: I know, sorry but I just don't believe in this. How can you store `char*`s in queue and have no ability to manage their memory?

Comment: @AndyT: you have to ask him, not me. I'm just reasoning about the data he gave us, and I made a very explicit question about this point. If, contrary to what he said, he is fully in charge of the deallocation of this stuff, which depends on dequeuing it from the FIFO, then of course you are right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`std::queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue). You insert elements at the end using `push()` and remove elements from the front using `pop()`. `front()` returns the front element.

To store `unsigned char*` elements, you'd declare a queue like this:

```
std::queue<unsigned char*> packetQueue;
```