# Push_front() alternative for a vector and operator++ for a map

Tags: c++, vector

I am getting compiler errors on these functions:

The compiler is complaining about push_front() on my vector, and also about the operator++ I attempted to use on my map.

I simply want to add a vector element at the front and add a new map entry, respectively.

```
 LanguageModel countSequence(LanguageModel &model, vector<string> &Seq) {    
    //append start and end to the vector of strings    
    vector<string>::iterator v = Seq.begin();    
    Seq.front();    
    Seq.("<START>");    
    v = Seq.end();    
    Seq.push_back("<END");    
    v = Seq.begin();


    //create word pairs    
    vector<string> pairs;     
    for (int n = 0; n <= Seq.size(); n++) {    
    pairs.at(n) = buildPair(Seq[n], Seq[n+1]);

    } 


    //feed each word to map 1 with number of times it was seen    
    for (int m = 0; m <= Seq.size(); m++) {    
    ++model.firstCounts[Seq[m]];    
    model.firstCounts[Seq[m]] =  count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[m]);

    }   


    //feed each word pair and the number of times it was seen    
    for (int k = 0; k <= Seq.size(); k++) {    
    ++model.pairCounts[Seq[k]];    
    model.pairCounts[Seq[k]] =  count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[k]);    
    }


    //feed each unique first word in a word pair and the second words in the pairs

    for (int l = 0; l <= Seq.size(); l++) {    
    istringstream iss(pairs[l]);    
     string sub;    
        iss >> sub;    
     string sub2;    
        iss >> sub2;   


        if (Seq[l] = sub) {    
            ++model.follows[sub];    
            model.follows[sub].push_back(sub2);     
        } 


    }


return model;    
}


string genNext(LanguageModel &model2, string &testWord, int Number) {    
    //use results of countSequence     
    string numbers[20]= model2.follows[testWord];    
    return numbers[Number];

}
```

These are the errors:

```
LangModel.cpp: In function ‘LanguageModel countSequence(LanguageModel&, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >&)’:
LangModel.cpp:38:6: error: ‘class std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘push_front’
Seq.push_front("<START>");

l.cpp:69:25: error: could not convert ‘(&(& Seq)->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::basic_string<char>, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char> > >(((std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::size_type)l)))->std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >((*(const std::basic_string<char>*)(& sub)))’ from ‘std::basic_string<char>’ to ‘bool’
if (Seq[l] = sub) {
                                     ^
LangModel.cpp:70:10: error: no match for ‘operator++’ (operand type is ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >::mapped_type {aka std::list<std::basic_string<char> >}’)
++model.follows[sub];
                      ^
LangModel.cpp: In function ‘std::string genNext(LanguageModel&, std::string&, int)’:
LangModel.cpp:81:45: error: conversion from ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::list<std::basic_string<char> > >::mapped_type {aka std::list<std::basic_string<char> >}’ to non-scalar type ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’ requested
string numbers[20]= model2.follows[testWord];
                                                     ^
```

Comment: I know it doesn't have a push_front(). That's why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inserting into a vector at the front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226606/inserting-into-a-vector-at-the-front)

Comment: [Here's a link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) to documentation on the C++ Standard Library containers - near the bottom there's a table showing which containers support which operations.

Comment: What do you need the ++ on the map/map element to do? From the error message, it looks like the values in the map are `std::list` objects, which don't have a ++ operator, and I'm not sure what ++ on a list _would_ do, if it had one...

Answer (score 4):

`std::vector` doesn't have a `push_front` because it would be extremely inefficient to add elements at the start of the vector (this would involve moving all existing elements one position to the right to make room for the new element). The alternative is to use `std::dequeue` instead of `std::vector`. It has a similar interface to `std::vector` but it doesn't offer the guarantee that all elements are in a contiguous memory zone, and so can implement insertions efficiently.

Regarding your second question, I don't understand exactly what you want to do with a map and an increment operator (and without the definitions of all the classes you use in the code above it's hard to guess).

`++` is a unary operator and the convention is that it does an *increment* on the operand (whatever *increment* means for the specific type of the operand). Basically `++object` should mean the same thing as `object = object + 1`. I'm not sure what meaning this operation might have for an `std::map`. You mentioned something about inserting into the map, but inserting what? `operator++` is unary, so you can't give it a parameter telling it what to insert.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, it seems like you want to add an element to the beginning of a vector without affecting the rest of the elements. For example, if you have a vector like `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`, you want to add the number 1 at the beginning to make it `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}`. I understand what you're looking for.

To achieve this, there is a convenient method we can use called `insert()` that is available for vectors:

```
vector<int> vec = {2, 3, 4, 5};
vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1);
```

By calling `vec.insert(vec.begin(), 1)`, we are inserting the value 1 at the beginning of the vector vec. This method automatically handles shifting the existing elements to the right, so you don't need to worry about damaging the other parts of the vector.

To fix this issue, you can remove the ++ operator and directly assign the count value returned by count to `model.firstCounts[Seq[m]]` and `model.pairCounts[Seq[k]]`.

Here's the corrected code:

```
for (int m = 0; m < Seq.size(); m++) {
    model.firstCounts[Seq[m]] = count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[m]);
}


for (int k = 0; k < Seq.size(); k++) {
    model.pairCounts[Seq[k]] = count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[k]);
}
```

In the corrected code, the count values returned by `count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[m])` and `count(Seq.begin(), Seq.end(), Seq[k])` are directly assigned to `model.firstCounts[Seq[m]]` and `model.pairCounts[Seq[k]]`, respectively, without using the ++ operator.

This approach should definitely help you. If any issues, please let me know!