# Add an element into the beginning of an vector, rest elements' position will add one

Tags: c++, vector

Assume I have an vector type of int(size 0). And I would like add elements into the beginning of the vector which would increase size by one. 
Like I have elements in an vector are 1 2 3 4 5. Now I use that method add 6 into it. It will output in this order 6 1 2 3 4 5.
Is that possible?

Comment: Yes! It is possible.

Comment: @UsamaZafar How do I do that?

Comment: Well that wasn't the question was it?

Comment: @UsamaZafar thank you for answering it then.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226606/inserting-into-a-vector-at-the-front

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4226606/1382251).

Comment: [std::vector::insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) or [std::deque::push_front](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/push_front).

Comment: Thank you guys, those help a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/

The following would be an example

```
int main ()
{
    std::vector<int> myvector;
    int myarray [] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), myarray, myarray+5);

    // Insert another value
    myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), 6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's it. Perhaps, I should have asked how to use insert method instead of my question.
** myvector.insert (myvector.begin(), myarray, myarray+5); **
what does the third part mean in this method?

Comment: It adds the array into the vector. It's the ending location+1

Comment: that would be the 'one-past-last' marker, see [iterators](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/stl/iterators.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val);
```

Is probably what you are looking for, the iterator for inserting at the beginning is vector::begin