# How to convert numbers into vector of integers?

Tags: c++, algorithm, parsing, number-formatting, stdvector

I want my program to ask the user to input any number and then store it into a `std::vector` where every single digit is allocated to a separate vector index:

```
input: 142

output vector: [1, 4, 2]
```

I tried this:

```
int main()
{
     std::vector<int> v;
     int number;
     cin >> number;
     for(unsigned int i = 100; i > 0; i/=10)
     {
         v.push_back(number/i);
         number -= (number/i)*i;
     }

     for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
     {
         std::cout<<v[i]<<std::endl;
     }
}
```

It works. But what should I do when the input-length is unknown?

Comment: what if the input is `-142` ? =]].
Read the input into a string and play with the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use simply `std::string` and for each `char`(which is actually integers) of string convert to integer as follows: [*SEE LIVE HERE*](https://www.ideone.com/TJvJUA)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string number = "123456789987654321";
    for(auto& Integer: number)
      v.emplace_back(static_cast<int>(Integer - '0'));

    for(const auto& it: v) std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

---

In case of entering unwanted characters/ user inputs(for example some negative numbers or even this: `+-1234567`), you can go for something with `try-catch`. `try` to convert the char to `int`, otherwise skip in the `catch` block as follows. [*SEE LIVE HERE*](https://www.ideone.com/1vX1XR)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <exception>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string number = "+-1234567";
    for(auto& Integer: number)
    {
        std::string Char(1, Integer); // convert to string
        try         {   v.emplace_back(std::stoi(Char));        }
        catch(...)  {   continue; }     // any case of exceptions

        /* or using much simpler std::isdigit from <cctype>
           by which conversion to std::string and try-catch can be avoided.

        if(std::isdigit(Integer))
            v.emplace_back(static_cast<int>(Integer - '0'));
        */
    }
    for(const auto& it: v) std::cout << it << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

*Edte*: As per @Aconcagua suggested, included the solution with `std::isdigit`

Comment: Reading into string is nice, but for checking on digits I'd rather use the C's good old `isdigit` function...

Comment: And why don't you just use the same conversion as in your first approach???

Comment: @Aconcagua I was trying with `atoi`. yes I missed it. My bad... Thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
while(number) {
  v.push_back(number%10);
  number /= 10;
}
std::reverse(v.begin(), v.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the `for` initilization `unsigned int i = number` rather than `unsigned int i = 100`. The re-written `for` statement will be:

```
for(unsigned int i = number; i > 0; i/=10)
```

Comment: ... and some adjustments in loop body.

Answer (score 1):

I you want to stay with digits and `std::deque` is an option you could do the following:

```
int main()
{
    std::deque<int> v;
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    while(number != 0)
    {
      v.push_front(number%10);
      number = number/10;
    }
    for(size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
    {
      std::cout<<v[i]<<std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the modulo operator you simply take the last digit and insert it in the front of the `deque`. Afterwards you "cut off" that digit with `/10`.

I used a deque, because [you can't push front with vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226606/inserting-into-a-vector-at-the-front).